In general, nested and unnested radical extensions have distinct Galois groups?
Say i have two distinct Galois field extensions $E_1/F$ and $E_2/F$, $F$ a zero characteristic field, such that the two following cases hold:
Case 1
The extension forms by ajoining the elements $\alpha\in E_1\wedge\alpha^n\in F$ and  $\beta\in E_1\wedge\beta^m\in F$:
$$E_1/F=F(\alpha,\beta)$$
Where, evidently, $[E_1:F]=nm$. The automorphisms of this extension should form a Galois group whose subgroups correspond to the subfield tower:
$$F\subseteq F(\alpha)\subseteq F(\alpha,\beta)$$
Case 2
The extension forms by ajoining the elements $\alpha\in E_2\wedge\alpha^n\in F$ and  $\beta\in E_2\wedge\beta^m\in F(\alpha)$:
$$E_2/F=F(\alpha,\beta)= [F(\alpha)](\beta)$$
Yet, similarly, we should have $[E_2:F]=nm$. And the automorphisms of this extension should form a Galois group whose subgroups correspond to the subfield tower:
$$F\subseteq F(\alpha)\subseteq[F(\alpha)](\beta)$$
Both cases are apparently very similar, but order seems to matter much more pronouncedly in the second case. This amounts to the fact that the second one has nested radicals, while the first one doesn't... But, are their Galois groups distinct? Nested and unnested radical extensions yield distinct Galois groups?

Yes, the Galois groups of the two cases differ in general. The nicest possible case is in the setup of Kummer theory where $F$ has all $(nm)^{th}$ roots of unity. Say that $\alpha$ is a root of an irreducible polynomial $t^n - a, a \in F$, so that the extension $F(\alpha)/F$ is a Kummer extension with Galois group $\mathbb{Z}/n$. Here a generator acts by $\alpha \mapsto \alpha \zeta_n$ where $\zeta_n$ is a primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity.
Now let's consider two possible further Kummer extensions of $F(\alpha)$:
Case 1: $\beta_1$ is the root of an irreducible polynomial of the form $t^m - b_1, b_1 \in F$ which remains irreducible over $F(\alpha)$. Then the extension $F(\beta_1, \alpha)/F(\alpha)$ is a Kummer extension with Galois group $\mathbb{Z}/m$, and so is the extension $F(\beta_1)/F$, and the extension $F(\beta_1, \alpha)/F$ is a compositum with Galois group the direct product $\mathbb{Z}/n \times \mathbb{Z}/m$, where the two factors act by roots of unity independently on $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
Case 2: $\beta_2$ is the root of an irreducible polynomial of the form $t^m - b_2, b_2 \in F(\alpha)$ over $F(\alpha)$. Then the extension $F(\beta_2, \alpha)/F(\alpha)$ continues to be a Kummer extension with Galois group $\mathbb{Z}/m$, but we can no longer say the same thing about the extension $F(\beta_2)/F$. In general this makes $F(\beta_2, \alpha)/F$ an extension with Galois group $G$ fitting into a short exact sequence
$$1 \to \mathbb{Z}/n \to G \to \mathbb{Z}/m \to 1$$
and this extension can be nontrivial, even nonabelian. As a simple class of examples, if in fact $b_2 = \alpha$ then $\beta_2 = \sqrt[nm]{a}$ so $F(\beta_2, \alpha)/F$ is itself a Kummer extension with Galois group $\mathbb{Z}/nm$, which is not generally the direct product $\mathbb{Z}/n \times \mathbb{Z}/m$, e.g. when $n = m$.
So an explicit minimal counterexample here is to take
$$F = \mathbb{Q}(i), n = m = 2, \alpha = \sqrt{2}, \beta_1 = \sqrt{3}, \beta_2 = \sqrt{\alpha} = \sqrt[4]{2}$$
where $F(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})/F$ has Galois group $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$ but $F(\sqrt[4]{2})/F$ has Galois group $\mathbb{Z}/4$.

Thanks! That's what i hadn't noticed yet: in the first case, the Galois group its formed by a direct product of groups, which causes the observed independency of the group action on the $n$-th roots. In the second case this condition mostly fails.
